# Rails query a search result as if it were a table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, inner-join, rails-activerecord, database-view

I'm trying to make an efficient way to search the results of a search.
Something like this:

```
search_results = Product.joins(:product_params).where(product_params: {name: name_a, value: value_a})
# do something to search_results to make it where I can further filter the results based on product_params
search_results = search_results.joins(:product_params).where(product_params: {name: name_b, value: value_b})
```

- ProductParam and Product are related via belongs_to / has_many.
- name in product_params is indexed.
- There's a large amount of products and product_params, so efficiency is important here.

Comment: What's the question? What do you mean with _search the results of a search_?

Comment: I want to get products that match multiple parameters. If the parameters were on the same table it would be something like .where(param_a: "value_a", param_b: "value_b").

I'm thinking something similar to a union of two different searches or making a temporary table based on the first search, then searching that table.

Comment: You could create a view and then query that as a table

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database view that you can then query like a model.
Here is a link to an article about it. There are lots of resources on the topic that also may be of help :D 
[Rails Database Views](http://www.sentia.com.au/blog/creating-database-views-with-rails)